# How to control the loop in javascript i.e. below code so that loop i stays var i= 1 to 4 and var j= 5 to 9

Tags: javascript

```
      How to control the loop in javascript i.e. below code so that loop i 
        stays var i= 1 to 4 and var j= 5 to 9 


         <script>

                    var max = 4;
                        var i =2;
                        var j=6;


// here code has 3 variable set max , i and j there two loops that should be i= 1to 4 and j = 5 to 9    and required is the code should stop at the last number instaead of i goes in negative or j goes more than 9                





            $(function() {
              var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');

              $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
                if (i < max+1) {
                  $('<br><p><label class="control-label requiredField" for="date">Date Of Birth<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label><input class="form-control" name="date[]" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="date"/><label class="control-label " for="health">Please Specify if you have or had any Health issue :</label><textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="health" name="health[]" placeholder="If no write Nill" rows="10"></textarea><label class="control-label ">Smoker</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="radio'+i+'" type="radio" value="Yes"/>Yes</label><label class="radio-inline"><input name="radio'+i+'" type="radio" value="No"/>No</label><br> <label class="control-label ">Gender</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input name="radio'+j+'" type="radio" value="Male"/>Male</label><label class="radio-inline"> <input name="radio'+j+'" type="radio" value="Female"/>Female</label><a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></button><p>').appendTo(scntDiv);


                  i++;
                    j++;



                  $('.remScnt').on('click', function() { 
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
                    j--;





                    return false;


                  });
                }

              });


            });
            </script>
```

here code has 3 variable set max , i and j there two loops that should be i= 1to 4 and j = 5 to 9  and required is the code should stop at the last number instaead of i goes in negative or j goes more than 9

Comment: max is for controlling how many elements i can add i.e. inside <p></p> i.e. 4

Comment: ques is quite unclear...

Comment: rephrase of question : i am adding element in html by javascript however when i run script above has 3 variable : max, i, , j . Now max is fixed , i and j are looping when element is added however when element is removed i need it should remove that element  index removed and startes from where it removed and should remain in that particular range for example when i =2 added element that name =name2 when remove name2 removed and when again added it adds name2 not name 3. hope that will make clear and when all 4 elements added and removed it gain starts with name2 instaed of giving -ve values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used break and continue for that

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
if (i === 3) { break; }
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
if (i === 3) { continue; }
 }
```

Comment: how could use in that script above posted